# Multiple WebResources output to html when using recursive server controls

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, webresource.axd

I have created a server control which uses recursion to create a menu. It essentially outputs nested lists with anchors inside them.

Now, this works perfectly, however, since the control is calling *itself* to render the child menus, it is also rendering multiple identical WebResource.axd javascript file references in .

Any idea how to stop this from happening? I just want the one reference in my  tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own problem by making a private constructor of the form:

```
private CustomControl(int level)
{
  this._Level = level + 1;
}
```

The public constructor looked like:

```
public CustomControl() : base()
{
  _Level = 1;
}
```

Then, when outputting the client scripts in the OnInit method, I checked whether _Level == 1, only outputting the client scripts if _Level == 1, like so:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnInit(e);

  if(_Level == 1)
  {
    // Add client scripts to this.Page.Header.Controls
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this was the best way, but it worked for me.